# I tried to write the program, but it is not working the way I want it. Please tell me what am I doing wrong

Tags: java

This is the question: **Modify the above program to sum all the numbers between 1 to 1000 that are divisible by 7**. 
This is my code:

```
int x=1;    
int y=1000;    
int number=x;    
int sum=0;      
while (number%7==0) {    
   sum=sum+number;    
   ++number;    
}    
System.out.printf("The sum of all numbers divisible by 7 from 1 to 100 is %d", sum);
```

Comment: And what happens? Always, always describe what you see vs what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int number=x;    
int sum=0;      
while (number<y) {    
   if (number%7==0) {
      sum+=number;
   }    
   number++;    
}
```

However there is more effective way. There is no need to loop by one, but loop by 7 and sum these numbers:

```
int d=7;    
int number = (x/d)*d;
int sum=0;
while (number < y-d) {
    n+=d;
    sum+=n;
}
```

`d` represents the divisor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like the approach of using a while loop when you know the bounds.

First, start by finding the highest possible :

```
int maximum = 1000 - 1000 % 7;//994
```

Then loop from first, until last, by step of 7.

```
for(int x = 7; x <= maximum; x += 7)
    sum += x;
```

No need to check with slow modulo as we have both bounds and increase by step of 7. Also notice the `<=`. The `=` is important here if we want to include the highest.

---

You could still do it with a `while` if you want, but in your example you are looping until you find a number which is not divisible by 7. You start at 1, so you will never enter. You need to loop between bounds and verify with an `if` if the current number is divisible by 7, then you sum.

Again since you know the bounds, the `for` loop shown above looks cleaner.

---

For completeness sake, using Java 8 you could achieve this with help of [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) :

```
IntStream
    .rangeClosed(7, maximum)
    .filter(i -> i % 7 == 0)
    .sum();
```

But this will be slower as `range` only allows incremental of 1 so we process each number and perform a modulo on each.

Comment: @Nichar Good point, edited.